# URLs which have the CONFIDENTIAL transport guarantee are still accessible using HTTP

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, https, web.xml

I did the following steps:
1) Created a self-signed certificate via keytool
2) Configured a connector on 8443 port in server.xml
3) Checked that both localhost:8080 and localhost:8433 are accessible
4) Added the following security constraint to my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/`, there is no redirect to `https://localhost:8443/MyApp/`. As far as I understand, requests using HTTP  for URLs whose transport guarantee is CONFIDENTIAL should be automatically redirected to the same URL using HTTPS.

However, my app remains accessible, and works using both HTTP and HTTPS. I am using Tomcat 6.0.36.
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks ok to me as long as it's correctly placed inside `<web-app>` and not nested inside anything else...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I found out that this behavior is caused by `secure` flag of HTTP connector. I set it previously for testing purposes, and forgot about it.

When HTTP connector has `secure="true"` and there are no existing JSESSIONID cookies in a browser:

- for HTTP requests JSESSIONID is stored in a URL
- for HTTPS requests JSESSIONID is stored in a cookie
- CONFIDENTIAL transport guarantee does not cause the redirect to the
  same URL using HTTPS

When HTTP connector has `secure="false"`:

- as expected, requests using HTTP for URLs whose transport guarantee
  is CONFIDENTIAL are automatically redirected to the same URL using
  HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

Actually this configuration works pretty well. With those settings you get 302 REDIRECT to https port. In normal case it happens transparently (e.g. in browser, postman) thats, why it works.
If you realy need to make sure if it works as expected you can use CURL with verbose output for that

```
curl -v http://localhost:80/your_resources/
```

then you will see each step and redirect command to

```
https://localhost:443/your_resources/
```